# Center video iframe without position: absolute

Tags: html, css, iframe, center, absolute

I'm trying to position a video iframe in the center of a page above an image gallery. I have the iframe nested in a wrapper, so my css goes wrapper div > video div > iframe. The issue is that I need to keep the video itself responsive while maintaining a 16:9 aspect ratio.

I was able to center the video using position: absolute, but I want to avoid that so I can keep everything clean and responsive and position images underneath it.

Here's my current code:

```
.video-wrapper {
  width: 60vw;

}

.video {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 -> 9/16x100 */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.video iframe {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

The image gallery beneath the video has these properties:

```
      .grid-container {
        margin:  auto 20vw;
        padding: 0 1vw 0 1vw;
        display: grid;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: .5vw;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 5vh;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox, flexbox make it easy to center an item vertically and horizontally on its parent, to center an item you just need to add flexbox desplay on the wrapper element and margin: auto to the item you want to center

```
.video-wrapper {
  width: 60vw;
  display: flex; 
}

.video {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 -> 9/16x100 */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```